# How do I prevent hash from escaping strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code that generates a hash used for testing the authentication of a internal Restful API.

The problem is the generated hash is returning escaped values.

The `json_headers` method should return something like this:

```
{"Authorization"=>"Basic ZnBfZXJwOllrdGh4aHRSZTZWM1d1d09oeVlmcW0xTg==", "Accept"=>"application/json"}
```

But is returning:

```
{\"Authorization\"=>\"Basic ZnBfZXJwOllrdGh4aHRSZTZWM1d1d09oeVlmcW0xTg==\\n\", \"Accept\"=>\"application/json\"}
```

Does anyone know an easy way to return raw key/values from a Ruby hash?

Here is the code:

```
module ERP
  class CustomersMock

    def json_headers
      authorization_hash.merge("Accept"=>"application/json")
    end

    def authorization_hash 
      {"Authorization" => "Basic #{base64_user_pass}"}
    end

    def user_pass
       # user:password
       [ ERP_CONF['user'], ERP_CONF['password'] ].join(':')
    end

    def base64_user_pass
      Base64.encode64(user_pass)
    end

    def add(customer)
      customers << customer
    end        

    def customers
      []
    end         

    def run
      ActiveResource::HttpMock.respond_to do |mock|
        customers.each do |customer|
          mock.get "/customers/#{customer.id}.json", json_headers, customer.to_json
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

For some reason, if I hard-code the headers hash in place, they work, but if I call the `json_headers` method, the `respond_to` block converts them to a string and escapes the values.

Here is the rspec failure:

```
Could not find a response recorded for <GET: /api/customers/1011.json [{"Authorization"=>"Basic ZnBfZXJwOllrdGh4aHRSZTZWM1d1d09oeVlmcW0xTg==", "Accept"=>"application/json"}] ()> - Responses recorded are: ["<GET: /api/customers/1011.json [{\"Authorization\"=>\"Basic ZnBfZXJwOllrdGh4aHRSZTZWM1d1d09oeVlmcW0xTg==\\n\", \"Accept\"=>\"application/json\"}] ()>"]
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `.as_json` after your hash declaration?

Comment: as_json will serialize the hash as valid json also escaping the key/values. The hash is not part of the json_payload it is the http headers. So it has to be in the format of {"Authorization"=>"Basic password"}.

Comment: @AaronRenoir, how are you inspecting the value returned by that method?

Comment: can you see what `mock.json_headers.class` returns? It should be `Hash`. If thats true, then I think your logger is escaping the string and in reality there is nothing escaped in hash. you can verify keys and values of it using `#keys, #values` methods

Comment: Dogbert good call, on the console it returns the hash as would be expected. But I am using it with http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveResource/HttpMock.html#method-c-requests and for some reason it is being converted to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not a escaping problem. I thought it was based on the rspec failing test output:

```
Could not find a response recorded for 
<GET: /api/customers/1011.json [{"Authorization"=>"Basic ZnBfZXJwOllrdGh4aHRSZTZWM1d1d09oeVlmcW0xTg==", "Accept"=>"application/json"}] ()> 

- Responses recorded are: [
"<GET: /api/customers/1011.json [{\"Authorization\"=>\"Basic ZnBfZXJwOllrdGh4aHRSZTZWM1d1d09oeVlmcW0xTg==\\n\", \"Accept\"=>\"application/json\"}] ()>"
]
```

It looks like the only difference is the headers hash is escaped in one and not in the other.

However, it is not escaping the line ending at the end of the "Authorization" value, so the fix is to strip the value:

```
def base64_user_pass
  Base64.encode64(user_pass).strip
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Escaped quotes are a bit confusing at first. I guess you were testing this from a REPL such as IRB or Pry. Your method actually contains normal double quotes – they are only escaped for output because double quotes are already used to denote the beginning and end of a string. That means that when you actually want to store the double quote character `"` in a string, you need to type `"\""` because if you were typing `"""` you would actually end the string with the second `"`. You can see what a string "really" contains by actually printing it with `puts`. Let me demonstrate this with an example:

```
require 'json'

h = {a: 123, b: 456}

h.to_json
#=> "{\"a\":123,\"b\":456}"       # note the escaped double quotes

puts h.to_json
# {"a":123,"b":456}               # when printed, quotes are no longer escaped

double_quote_1 = '"'              # another way to store " in a string
double_quote_2 = "\""
double_quote_1 == double_quote_2  # both have the same contents, a single "
#=> true

json1 = '{"a":123,"b":456}'       # less confusing way of writing the json from above
json2 = "{\"a\":123,\"b\":456}"
json1 == json2
#=> true
```

Comment: yes thanks for info on how rails serializes a hash to json. I edited my question to show how i am using the hasn. I am trying to generate a hash for the request_headers option @ http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveResource/HttpMock.html . I can hard code the value into the request_headers option and it works so it tells me there is a difference between writing in the hash like so {"Authorization"=>"Basic password"} and passing in a function that returns the same hash.

Comment: I got it. The escaping was throwing me off because rspec lead me astray. It showed the difference as being escaped values. But the real difference was the Base64.encode64(user_pass) was adding a line ending that wasn't in the request. Sorry for the bad question.